# how can I connect a scanner with Centronics 50 output to USB?

Tags: hardware

How can I connect a Legacy scanner with a Centronics 50 output to a laptop with USB ?

Comment: Do you know what protocol it speaks? It sounds like maybe SCSI.

Comment: With information about mark and model someone might be able to give a correct answer. With the current information it will only be more or less qualified guesses.

Comment: If it's really a 50 pin Centronics connector, then it's SCSI. You've actually got two problems here: Even if you get a USB to SCSI adapter, you still need to find drivers for your laptop that will talk to that scanner. Any scanner that is old enough to be SCSI may well not have drivers available for a modern OS. Please let us know the OS on the laptop as well as the scanner's model.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what protocol the scanner uses. If it is SCSI you need a USB to SCSI converter. If it is parallel port you need a USB to parallel port converter, although be aware that sometimes they are not compatible with scanners.